# What do the 3 phases of the election mean?

Tags: support, election

The [2014 Moderator Election page](https://unix.stackexchange.com/election) states:

```
Every election has three phases:

1. Nomination
2. Primary
3. Election
```

However, there is no (complete) explanation of the phases; currently -- I presume until the first phase is over -- the [primary](https://unix.stackexchange.com/election/2?tab=primary) and [election](https://unix.stackexchange.com/election/2?tab=election) tabs provide no information.

I believe I've also seen a timeline for the three phases somewhere, but it is not on that page.  Does anyone know where that is, and/or have a link **explaining the Stack Exchange election process**?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a blue box on the right side of the election page that explains the phase you're currently looking at; it also explains how long that phase lasts. A quick summary:

- **Nomination** is 7 days of anyone with 300 rep entering their name as a candidate, including a short introduction. Anyone can comment on the nominations
- **Primary** is 4 days of up/down voting on each nomination, to cut the number down to 10 for the final election. Since it looks like we won't have more than 10 nominations, we'll skip this part
- **Election** is 7 days of anyone with 150 rep voting on the final candidates, using [meek STV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meek%27s_method#Meek.27s_method)

We're about to finish the nomination phase and go into the election, so it'll be over in a week

Comment: Facepalm -- did not notice the blue box changed for each tab.